# Google calendar event api - How to set "modify event" to true in Author's calender?

Tags: api, calendar, author

I have a requirement of setting "Modify Event" to true in Author's calender.
- An user used to send API query is one of the Guest user added as a participant when an event was created.

- Is it possible to get write access to some other user's calender events?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured this out:

You need to create "Service account" through Google Developer Console. And use this user for making API calls.
When you need to update events created by other google user, you need to impersonate this user by service account and then service account will be able to make modifications to that event.