# Set modify event to true while creating an event in google calendar

Tags: ruby, google-calendar-api, google-api-client

Is there a way to set the value of `modify event` to true while creating an event? I am using google-api-client gem. I want the invited participant to be able edit the google calendar event as well

BTW I have found this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22797985/google-calendar-event-api-how-to-set-modify-event-to-true-in-authors-calend) but is there another way to do it? If i follow that approach, the events will be created in the service account and not in the user's account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer. https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events#resource i needed to add `"guestsCanModify": true`